# Use WFC service calls as UserStore for ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, wcf, webforms, asp.net-identity

I am creating a web forms application that uses a WCF service to interact with the database and other applications. This web forms application has no access to the database.

I would like to use ASP.Net Identity for user management. I have already created a custom UserStore and RoleStore by following this tutorial, [Overview of Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity), as shown below.

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<IdentityUser, long>, IUserRoleStore<IdentityUser, long>
{
    UserServiceClient userServiceClient = new UserServiceClient();

    public Task CreateAsync(IdentityUser user)
    {
        string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserName();
        Genders gender = (Genders)user.CoreUser.Gender.GenderId;

        UserDto userDto = userServiceClient.CreateUser(user.CoreUser.FirstName, user.CoreUser.LastName, gender, user.CoreUser.EmailAddress, user.CoreUser.Username, userName, user.CoreUser.Msisdn);

        return Task.FromResult<UserDto>(userDto);
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync(IdentityUser user)
    {
        bool success = userServiceClient.DeactivateUser(user.CoreUser.UserId, "");

        return Task.FromResult<bool>(success);
    }

    public Task<IdentityUser> FindByIdAsync(long userId)
    {
        UserDto userDto = userServiceClient.GetUserByUserId(userId);

        return Task.FromResult<IdentityUser>(new IdentityUser { CoreUser = userDto, UserName = userDto.Username });
    }

    public Task<IdentityUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        UserDto userDto = userServiceClient.GetUserByUsername(userName);

        return Task.FromResult<IdentityUser>(new IdentityUser { CoreUser = userDto, UserName = userDto.Username });
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(IdentityUser user)
    {
        Genders gender = (Genders)user.CoreUser.Gender.GenderId;

        UserDto userDto = userServiceClient.UpdateUserDetails(user.CoreUser.UserId, user.CoreUser.FirstName, user.CoreUser.LastName, gender, user.CoreUser.EmailAddress, user.CoreUser.Msisdn, "");

        return Task.FromResult<UserDto>(userDto);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task AddToRoleAsync(IdentityUser user, string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(IdentityUser user)
    {
        List<UserRoleDto> roles = userServiceClient.GetUserRoles(user.Id);

        return Task.FromResult<IList<string>>(roles.Select(r => r.Role.RoleName).ToList());
    }

    public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(IdentityUser user, string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(IdentityUser user, string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();            
    }
}
```

That is the UserStore. Now the issue is implementing this for Identity.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

In the class above that comes predefined with the template, there's the line:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
```

Now I don not have an ApplicationDbContext since this is handled in the WCF. Also, in the IdentityConfig class in the App_Start folder, there's the method Create that has this line,

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

Again, i have no idea with what to replace the ApplicationDbContext. Am I doing this right? Is the tutorial I followed sufficient to help me with what I need?

Comment: I have the same scenario, but I need to provide a token to my web service from the UserStore for FindByIdAsync. How did you do it? Did you enable anonymous access for userServiceClient.GetUserByUsername(userName) ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this link, [ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Extending Identity Models and Using Integer Keys Instead of Strings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/798001/ASP-NET-Identity-Extending-Identity-Models-and-Usi)

The issue was more about the fact that my user id was an `long` instead of the default string. I also did not need to pass the context as my `UserStore` did not expect a context in it's constructor